# Checking for significance in several variables independently

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, linear-model

I believe this question is very simple, but I can't seem to google it right.

I have data on the efficiency o vehicles (Km/L) for several different routes, vehicles, models and several other categorical variables. Here some example data in R:

```
set.seed(1)
reprexData = data.frame(
  "vehicleEfficiency" = rnorm(20,mean=2.5,sd=0.6),
  "vehicleMake" = sample(c("Volvo","Volkswagen","Audi","Mercedes"),20,replace=T),
  "driverClass" = sample(c("A","B",20,replace=T)),
  "company" = sample(c("C1","C2"),20,replace=T),
  "route" = sample(c("X->B","X->A","Y->C"),20,replace=T)
)
```

I know that the routes are very different: some are uphill, some are downhill and others are flat. So I expect that the efficiency should change from route to route.

I want to test the influence of each other variable on the efficiency independently, while controlling for the different routes. Can I do something like this:

```
mod = lm(vehicleEfficiency ~ vehicleMake + driverClass + company + route,data=reprexData)
anova(mod)
```

And use the p-values from `anova` to determine significance? Am I already controlling for routes by including it in the model?

Or do I need to separate the data by route and test for significance on each route independently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a mixed effects model and include route as a random variable. This will allow you to test for an effect of vehicleMake, driverClass and company, while excluding the variation between routes.

You can do this in R if you load the lme4 package:

```
library(lme4)
mod <- lmer(vehicleEfficiency ~ vehicleMake + driverClass + company + (1|route),data=reprexData)
summary(mod)
```